# How can disable WebView's contextmenu?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, webview

I want to disable WebView's contextmenu "Reload", "Open Link", "Open Link in new Window", "Download link" etc..
I've tried a really long time, this method with contextMenuItemsForElement, but no matter how I try do not work
I really feel very sad, I hope someone can help me, I would be very grateful.

The following is my code：

```
@class WebView;
@interface UIWebView (Client)
- (NSArray *)webView:(WebView *)sender contextMenuItemsForElement:(NSDictionary *)element defaultMenuItems:(NSArray *)defaultMenuItem;
@end

@implementation UIWebView (Client)
- (NSArray *)webView:(WebView *)sender contextMenuItemsForElement:(NSDictionary *)element 
    defaultMenuItems:(NSArray *)defaultMenuItems
{
    NSLog(@"contextMenuItemsForElement");
    return nil;
}

@end
```

Why are not working?

Comment: Are you sure you're trying to do this on iOS? Sounds like a Mac OS api.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think `webView:contextMenuItemsForElements:` is available in the iPhone SDK (or at least publicly).

If you have control over the html/css code, you can put this rule in your css

```
a {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none !important;
}
```

and if it isn't possible, try

```
[yourWebView stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString:@"var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { a.style.WebkitTouchCallout = 'none'; }"];
```

in your `webViewDidFinishLoad:` method.

Comment: I did it! Really thank you so much, CSS did not expect such a function, but I still do not understand why webView: contextMenuItemsForElements this method will not play? Is the iphone does not support? Only Mac OS X?

Comment: That was it! I must admit I was a rookie, but English is not good, so many things that do not understand. I feel very confused, because I was in http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebUIDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html find webView: contextMenuItemsForElements: This method, if This is the Mac OS API, but why I can use webView:runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage, webView:runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage etc.. methods? is this not the Mac OS API?

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a solution to disable long press context menu using UIKit Overrides for menu building and validation. Add this in your ViewController.m file**

```
-(void)buildMenuWithBuilder:(id<UIMenuBuilder>)builder {
    NSLog(@"%@", builder);
    [builder removeMenuForIdentifier:UIMenuLookup];
    [builder removeMenuForIdentifier:UIMenuShare];
    [builder removeMenuForIdentifier:UIMenuStandardEdit];
}
```

**Note: import UIKit** `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`